# Dynamic jQuery identifier gives "Object doesn't support this property or method" in IE8, using jquery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dynamic

does somebody know, why this throws an error in IE8?

```
$(function(){
    function activateTab(name){
       identifier = '#' + name;
       container = $(identifier);
    }
});
```

thanks for any advise.

Comment: try `console.log(name); console.log(container)` at the end of the function and tell us what you get

Comment: Have you included jQuery in your page? Is this code running afer `document.ready`?

Comment: Chrome on MacOS X: name: tab-prozess, identifier: #tab-prozess, container: [<div id="tab-prozess">...</div>]. IE8 on Windows XP: LOG: name:tabprozess, LOG: identifier:#tab-prozess, "Object doesn't support this property or method", Line: "container = $(identifier);

Answer (score 1):

Should work fine, wrap your code in **$(document).ready** function, like

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  alert(activateTab("test"));
});
function activateTab(name){
   identifier = '#' + name;
   container = $(identifier);
   return container;
}
<div id="test">Tested</div>
```

Try:

```
$(function(){
    function activateTab(name){
       identifier = '#' + name;
       container = $(identifier);
        return container;
    }
    alert(activateTab("test"));
});
```

This is also working fine for me

Comment: thanks, but i'm doing this already. I'm using the shorter one, edited my post.

Comment: Chrome on MacOS X: [object Object], IE8 on Windows XP: "Object doesn't support this property or method", Line: "container = $(identifier);"... Argh...